# $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \Gamma\left(k+\alpha\right) \, \frac{t^k}{k!}=??$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, special-functions, gamma-function

I'm trying to compute:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k} \Gamma\left(\frac{2k+n+m-1}{2}\right)}{k!} \,  x^{2k}.$$

I thought of the expression of the binomial series
$${\displaystyle (1+x)^{\alpha }=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\binom {\alpha }{n}}x^{n}} \qquad (*)$$
where
$${\displaystyle {\binom {\alpha }{n}}={\frac {\alpha (\alpha -1)\cdots (\alpha -n+1)}{n!}}} \quad (\text{the generalized binomial coefficients}).$$
i.e.,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k} \Gamma\left(\frac{2k+n+m-1}{2}\right)}{k!} \,  x^{2k}&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \Gamma\left(\frac{2k+n+m-1}{2}\right) \,  \frac{(-x^{2})^k}{k!}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \Gamma\left(k+\frac{n+m-1}{2}\right) \,  \frac{(-x^{2})^k}{k!}.
\end{align*}
In other words:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \Gamma\left(k+\alpha\right) \,  \frac{t^k}{k!}=??
\end{align*}
What do I have to do, in order to get to the expreesion $(*)$. Thank's

Comment: It's more convenient to put $n+m-1 = j$ and $t=-x^2$ and work with $j$ and $t$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite series with gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2619485/infinite-series-with-gamma-function)

Comment: @Botnakov, No. Because, I have $\Gamma(k+\alpha)$ not $\Gamma(\frac{k}{2}+\alpha)$.

Comment: This one can help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2132666 Look at the series in the question.

Comment: Use the fact that $\Gamma(k + \alpha) = (\alpha)_k \Gamma(\alpha)$, where $(\,\cdot\,)_k$ is the Pochhammer symbol, and your sum looks like $\Gamma(\alpha)\sum_0^\infty\, (\alpha)_k t^k /k!$. Then have a look at the function ${}_1F_0(\alpha, -, t)$ and its simplification.

Comment: Your sum is hypergeometric so an approach identical to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538626/evaluating-the-sum-sum-k-1n-frackka-for-a-parameter-a) should provide a closed form for the partial sums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $|t|<1$. We have \begin{eqnarray*}
\Gamma(z) = \int_0 ^{\infty} x^{z-1} e^{-x} dx \Longrightarrow 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ \Gamma(n+s)}{n!}t^n  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0 ^{\infty} \frac{t^n x^{n+s-1} e^{-x}}{n!} dx
\end{eqnarray*}
Now invert the sum & integral
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0 ^{\infty}  x^{s-1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(tx)^{n} }{n!}  e^{-x}dx =\int_0 ^{\infty} x^{s-1} e^{x(t-1)} dx
\end{eqnarray*}
Put $u = x(1-t)$. We have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ \Gamma(n+s)}{n!}t^n = \int_0 ^{\infty} \frac{u^{s-1}}{(1-t)^{s-1}} e^{-u} \frac{du}{1-t} = \frac{1}{(1-t)^s}\int_0^{\infty}u^{s-1}e^{-u}du = \frac{\Gamma(s)}{(1-t)^s}$$

Addition: if $|t| \ge 1$ and $s \ge 1$ then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ \Gamma(n+s)}{n!}t^n$ diverges because $ \frac{ \Gamma(n+s)}{n!}t^n \not \to 0$, $n \to \infty$.